# Pitivi blank box

Tags: pitivi

Where the layer settings (I think) box should be in Pitivi 0.93 in Ubuntu 14.10, there's only a white box.

[image: The white box]

Terminal output when starting Pitivi:

```
(pitivi:8218): Clutter-WARNING **: clutter_x11_set_use_argb_visual() can only be used before calling clutter_init()

(pitivi:8218): Clutter-WARNING **: clutter_x11_set_display() can only be used before calling clutter_init()

(pitivi:8218): Clutter-WARNING **: clutter_x11_disable_event_retrieval() can only be used before calling clutter_init()

(pitivi:8218): Clutter-WARNING **: clutter_disable_accessibility() can only be called before initializing Clutter.
Missing soft dependency:
- pycanberra not found on the system
    -> enables sound notifications when rendering is complete
Missing soft dependency:
- GnomeDesktop not found on the system
    -> file thumbnails provided by GNOME's thumbnailers

(pitivi:8218): Gdk-WARNING **: gdk_window_set_icon_list: icons too large
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pitivi/python/pitivi/project.py:559: TypeError: Passing arguments to gi.types.Boxed.__init__() is deprecated. All arguments passed will be ignored.
  Gst.Caps("application/ogg"),
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pitivi/python/pitivi/project.py:563: TypeError: Passing arguments to gi.types.Boxed.__init__() is deprecated. All arguments passed will be ignored.
  video_profile = GstPbutils.EncodingVideoProfile.new(Gst.Caps("video/x-theora"),
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pitivi/python/pitivi/project.py:565: TypeError: Passing arguments to gi.types.Boxed.__init__() is deprecated. All arguments passed will be ignored.
  Gst.Caps("video/x-raw"),
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pitivi/python/pitivi/project.py:569: TypeError: Passing arguments to gi.types.Boxed.__init__() is deprecated. All arguments passed will be ignored.
  audio_profile = GstPbutils.EncodingAudioProfile.new(Gst.Caps("audio/x-vorbis"),
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pitivi/python/pitivi/project.py:571: TypeError: Passing arguments to gi.types.Boxed.__init__() is deprecated. All arguments passed will be ignored.
  Gst.Caps("audio/x-raw"),
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pitivi/python/pitivi/project.py:792: TypeError: Passing arguments to gi.types.Boxed.__init__() is deprecated. All arguments passed will be ignored.
  self.container_profile.set_format(Gst.Caps(muxertype))
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pitivi/python/pitivi/project.py:771: TypeError: Passing arguments to gi.types.Boxed.__init__() is deprecated. All arguments passed will be ignored.
  self.video_profile.set_format(Gst.Caps(videotype))
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pitivi/python/pitivi/project.py:751: TypeError: Passing arguments to gi.types.Boxed.__init__() is deprecated. All arguments passed will be ignored.
  self.audio_profile.set_format(Gst.Caps(audiotype))
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gi/overrides/GLib.py:548: Warning: Source ID 38 was not found when attempting to remove it
  super(MainLoop, self).run()

And when I import video and drag it to the layer area (when the white box appears):

(pitivi:8362): Gdk-WARNING **: gdk_window_set_icon_list: icons too large

(pitivi:8362): Clutter-WARNING **: Unable to query pixmap: 44019c2

(pitivi:8362): Clutter-WARNING **: Unable to query pixmap: 44019c4

(pitivi:8362): Clutter-WARNING **: Unable to query pixmap: 44019c6

(pitivi:8362): Clutter-WARNING **: Unable to query pixmap: 44019c8

(pitivi:8362): Clutter-WARNING **: Unable to query pixmap: 44019ca

(pitivi:8362): Clutter-WARNING **: Unable to query pixmap: 44019cc

(pitivi:8362): Clutter-WARNING **: Unable to query pixmap: 44019ce

(pitivi:8362): Clutter-WARNING **: Unable to query pixmap: 44019ff

(pitivi:8362): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: _gst_util_uint64_scale: assertion 'denom != 0' failed

(pitivi:8362): Clutter-WARNING **: Unable to query pixmap: 4401af2

(pitivi:8362): Clutter-WARNING **: Unable to query pixmap: 4401b19

(pitivi:8362): Clutter-WARNING **: Unable to query pixmap: 4401b40

(pitivi:8362): Clutter-WARNING **: Unable to query pixmap: 4401b67

(pitivi:8362): Clutter-WARNING **: Unable to query pixmap: 4401b8e

(pitivi:8362): Clutter-WARNING **: Unable to query pixmap: 4401bb5
```

More `(pitivi:8362): Clutter-WARNING **: Unable to query pixmap: <blahblah>` is dumped when trying to interact with the white box (It can be drug down and strings back).

Changing gnome theme and restart the app changes nothing.

There are two horizontal areas within the white box that respond right click events and show a context menu about moving or deleting a layer.

Comment: Maybe you should use the Pitivi version which is available in the Ubuntu archive then, i.e. 0.93-4ubuntu1.

Comment: D'oh! My bad! I accidentally wrote down 0.94 when I meant to write 0.93. fixed it now.

Comment: Can you start pitivi from a terminal window and add the resulting terminal output to your question.

Comment: Added the terminal output.

Comment: Thanks. It does not seem to work for me either. The current 14.10 version is a result of fixes in [bug #1307746](https://launchpad.net/bugs/1307746). You may want to report your findings there. Also, you may want to try the [vivid version](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/pitivi/0.93-4.2) and see if it possibly works better.

Comment: How can I install the vivid version?

Comment: Assuming you have a 64 bit OS, download the [amd64 .deb file](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/vivid/amd64/pitivi/0.93-4.2) and install it with `sudo dpkg -i <path-to-file>`. Otherwise pick the i386 .deb file.

Comment: Ah! Thanks. Wasn't sure how to get the .deb file. I installed it, stil has the same issue.

Comment: Then I can just suggest that you file a bug (or comment on that old bug report). Fixing it would be over my head. Sorry.